# SQL query works even with wrong syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am running a SQL query in stored procedure which is like following

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,t2.Name
FROM 
    table1 t1 , table2 t2 ,table2 t3,table4 t4
WHERE 
    t1.id=t3.t4.id
```

this query gets executed  on SQL server 2008 when its compatible with SQL server 2000 but if we turn OFF the compatibility with SQL server 2000 then this Query gives syntax error which is expected.
Can some one help me to understand why this is happeneing ? thanks in advance

---

Original query:

```
SELECT
      ConfigID , LocationDesc + '-' + LOBTeamDesc LocLOBTeamSource
FROM Config CONFIG , Location_LOBTeam LOCLOB , Location LOC , LOBTeam LOB, System SRC
WHERE CONFIG.LocationLOBTeamID = LOC.LOB.LocationLOBTeamID
      AND CONFIG.SourceSystemID = SRC.SystemID
      AND LOCLOB.LocationID = LOC.LocationID
      AND LOCLOB.LOBTeamID = LOB.LOBTeamID
      AND (GETDATE() BETWEEN CONFIG.effectiveDate AND CONFIG.EndDate
      OR CONFIG.EndDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY
      LOC.LocationCode
```

Comment: Can you add the exception text please?

Comment: Join syntax deprecation: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2008/09/13/deprecation-of-old-style-join-syntax-only-a-partial-thing.aspx

Comment: Is there a typo on the where clause in your sample? Is `t3.t4.id` correct? I assume this isn't your real query, hence my question.

Comment: Exception text is t4 is not a valid column name

Comment: There are too many error in that "simplified query" and it cannot be used for answering IMHO e.g. `t1.id=t3.t4.id` that won't work in any dbms, and if that is resolved you would have multiple Cartesian products because you haven't listed the join conditions. Please re-look at the original query, either faithfully summarize it, or display it in whole here.

Comment: `t1=t3.id` or it is `t1.id=t4.id` but we cannot know which one is correct

Comment: Hi Tanner, No its not typo in where clause though its not my original query but scenario is like where clause contains alias1.alias2.column name and still its working thats why I wonder how its working

Comment: Just add your real query, trimmed down slightly if required. It may show something that's not apparent in your example.

Comment: @Used_By_Already where exactly does OP state that this is a "simplified" version of his erroring query?

Comment: 'SELECT 
 ConfigID, LocationDesc + '-' + LOBTeamDesc LocLOBTeamSource 
FROM 
 Config CONFIG, Location_LOBTeam LOCLOB,Location LOC, LOBTeam LOB,System SRC
WHERE 
 CONFIG.LocationLOBTeamID = LOC.LOB.LocationLOBTeamID
 AND CONFIG.SourceSystemID = SRC.SystemID
 AND LOCLOB.LocationID = LOC.LocationID
 AND LOCLOB.LOBTeamID = LOB.LOBTeamID
 AND (getDate() between CONFIG.effectiveDate and CONFIG.EndDate
 OR CONFIG.EndDate IS NULL)

ORDER BY
LOC.LocationCode'

Comment: @SelectDistinct it does not. If I am wrong so be it, but if the OP does have `table1` `table2` `table3` and `table4` with fields of `t1` etc. then I wish them the very best of luck, but suggest they adopt a better naming convention in future. Plus, given there is only one bogus join condition that will not work in either version of mssql, my assessment is some "translation" has been applied. Is it wrong to apply judgments of this kind that are aimed to help?

Comment: @Used_By_Already I posted the original query this may help you to suggest me something

Comment: :) I was replying to @SelectDistinct (good name btw) while you posted that code. But you should have included that in the question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below post from msdn answers this issue  [Compatibility Levels and Stored Procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

in the above post the point number 3 under section "Differences Between Compatibility Level 80 and Level 90" states "WHEN binding the column references in the ORDER BY list to the columns defined in the SELECT list, column ambiguities are ignored and column prefixes are sometimes ignored. This can cause the result set to return in an unexpected order."
on my database I am using compatibility level 80 i.e 2000 thats why it runs smoothly with the given syntax but  when I remove this compatibility and make it to 100 i.e. 2008/R2 script gives syntax error which is expected

Answer (score 0):

I think that original query, with current standard join syntax applied would be this:

```
SELECT
      ConfigID
    , LocationDesc + '-' + LOBTeamDesc LocLOBTeamSource
FROM Config CONFIG
      INNER JOIN Location_LOBTeam LOCLOB
                  ON CONFIG.LocationLOBTeamID = LOCLOB.LocationLOBTeamID
      INNER JOIN Location LOC
                  ON LOCLOB.LocationID = LOC.LocationID
      INNER JOIN LOBTeam LOB
                  ON LOCLOB.LOBTeamID = LOB.LOBTeamID
      INNER JOIN [System] SRC
                  ON CONFIG.SourceSystemID = SRC.SystemID
WHERE (GETDATE() BETWEEN CONFIG.effectiveDate AND CONFIG.EndDate
      OR CONFIG.EndDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY
      LOC.LocationCode
```

Perhaps this will help.

+EDIT
"System" as a table name, could that be a problem? Suggest you try it as [System]

+EDIT2
The original is given with this: `LOC.LOB.LocationLOBTeamID` but that appears to be an error as there is an alias LOCLOB

Comment: I also thought so that the instead of  `LOC.LOB` it should be `LOCLOB` but its same as I posted in Question  `CONFIG.LocationLOBTeamID = LOC.LOB.LocationLOBTeamID`, can you suggest me something else

Comment: NO, I cannot. if it is not `LOCLOB` then the table with that alias is not joined. Why to you believe it isn't `LOCLOB`? what is the evidence for this?

Comment: Perhaps you could try NO ALIASES?

Comment: @Usded_By_Already How do I show the evidence of this , but  let me tell you what I did , I am running the query on SQL server 2008 first I enabled compatiblity to SQL server 2000  at that time this query was working even we know that its syntax error and when I disabled the compatibility with SQL server 2000 the query stopped working and throwing an error as we are expecting , thats the reason I asked this question

Comment: I wonder how can query run with syntax error or is there something that I am missing ?

Comment: @Sanket Nagone, magic I am not :( I can look at the evidence in front of me and asses that `LOC.LOB.LocationLOBTeamID` is an obvious syntax error. As you are adamant it works in SQL 2000 compatibility I can only `suggest` that the parser has either forgiven the author or ignored the problem. Truly, I don't believe I can offer more than I have.

Comment: @Usded_By_Already Thanks for your help , I will try to find out the reason for this and if I find anything remarkable I will definately let you know